# Azure Pipeline build multiple solutions "checkin" build

Tags: xaml, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, yaml, azure-devops-server-2019

I am moving from "XAML" builds to DevOps YAML builds and trying to replicate what I had in TFS 2012.  In the XAML build I had several "Solutions" in the "Items to build" and this build was triggered on any checkin.  From what I can tell the Pipeline was designed to build a single solution.  I've "unlinked" the Pipeline from a single solution and was planning on adding additional Build Tasks for each solution to build.  Is this the proper way?  If this is not the best way to do this I'm open to suggestions.  Using Azure DevOps 2019 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Hi dblwizard, any update on this issue, have you figure out it? Just checking to see if my reply helped. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer* which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you are able to do this. If you manage to do this with if's or something like that, you have to add multiple  tasks - to each solution. You have to deal with triggers, finally your yaml file would be unmaintainable. YAML script would be huge and difficult to understand the dependencies.

I would suggest you just use a single file for each solution build. You are able to have many of `.yml` files all targeting different solutions.

- [Multiple YAML build pipelines in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766890/multiple-yaml-build-pipelines-in-azure-devops)
- [Can I have multiple build pipelines for the same repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012697/can-i-have-multiple-build-pipelines-for-the-same-repository)

Besides, since you are moving from "XAML" and not familiar with this build process. You can always use the Designer approach and pull out the system generated YAML if you are new to the system. Here's the [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) reference that might help you!!!

[image]